# How to create a separator bar with title?

Tags: android, titlebar, separator

I want to create a separator bar with title like this:

[image]

I searched a bit but couldn't find any widget which provides this functionality. Could anyone shed me a light on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995940/best-native-component-to-use-for-separate-listview-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called `Sectioned List`. And you can do this using a "SectionedListAdapter"

There are many implementations around the internet, [Jeff Sharkley](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/), and [this one](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The example link is really helpful and easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

There are many widgets round web few of which are

1. [android-section-list](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)
2. [dhammapada-android](https://github.com/appamatto/dhammapada-android)
3. [Alphabetic FastScroll ListView - similar to Contacts](http://www.anddev.org/alphabetic_fastscroll_listview_-_similar_to_contacts-t10123.html)

Comment: What a nice list, thanks a lot. Dunno the name of widget is such an annoying thing.